# Prospective juror being held in contempt for their opinions

Tags: united-states, jury

From my understanding, prospective jurors will be asked a series of questions which will determine if the attorneys think that person is a good candidate to serve on the jury.  Does a prospective juror, prior to being selected, have the right to remain silent during this process?

Regardless of whether a prospective juror has that right or not; is it more likely that a judge will hold that person in contempt for refusing to answer, or more likely that the person will just not be selected as a juror?

Lastly, it is likely for a prospective juror to be held in contempt if they express opinions such as all police are liars and not to be trusted, District Attorneys care more about being re-elected and looking tough on crime than they do about actual justice, or saying something akin to the US court system being a money-making scheme for privatized prisons?

I am worried about being held in contempt of court for any of the above or just generally having a bad attitude about the whole thing.  Am I being unrealistic?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Where do yyou get your opinion on the judge holding the jurors in contempt before either party throwing out the juror *for cause*?

Comment: Why would you be held in contempt for telling the truth about about how you feel regarding issues related to the case? That is the entire point of those questions

Answer (score 2):

### A juror can’t be in contempt for their opinions

**They can be in contempt for their behaviour; which may include how they express their opinions.** There are ways of expressing negative opinions of the police, the prosecutor and even the judge that are respectful, and ways that are not; the former is fine, the latter is contempt.

Notwithstanding, deliberately not answering a judge’s questions is in contempt.